# Correct way to create a foreign key based on type, in SQL Server and Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I use Entity Framework Core and SQL Server in my application. I am very familiar with foreign keys but I would like to learn the correct way to give a foreign key to an entity which is based on a type.

For example:

Parent class `AppUser`:

```
CREATE TABLE AppUser
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UserTypeId SMALLINT NOT NULL --  !This is the important part for me! if 0 = Student if 1 = Teacher
);

CREATE TABLE Student
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    AppUserId INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_Student_AppUser FOREIGN KEY (AppUserId)
    REFERENCES AppUser(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Teacher
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    AppUserId INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_Student_AppUser FOREIGN KEY (AppUserId)
    REFERENCES AppUser(Id)
);
```

My question: is there a better way to have this relationship. Because in Entity Framework, when I try to get a user, I always need to check for the `TypeId` and have an if else block for the type, then make the query on the table student or teacher. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you're trying to achieve? Your `UserTypeId` column- what is its purpose?

Comment: @PlamenYordanov For example when I try to update the student, I post the AppUser Id to the .net web api. Then, i have to get the AppUser with that Id. then I should make an if block such as: if(user.TypeId == 0) // update student. I directly want to get the student object without writing an if block

Comment: Well, there must be a condition that is met before updating a particular user, you have to identify the object in some way. How are you getting your user?

Answer (score 0):

According to your table structures, if you want to get student through AppUser Id, you can directly use this code :

```
 var data = _context.Student.Include(x => x.AppUser).Where(x => x.AppUserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Next, you only need to distinguish the parameter of `data` .

If data is `null`, it represents  that the Id of AppUser is not a student but a teacher(*which means the UserTypeId field value is 1*), otherwise, you can update the student fields you want.

```
           if (data != null)
            {
               //update student
            }
```